# WordPress: post_type->rewrite['slug'] returns post_type, not the slug

Tags: wordpress

In my application I need to create a widget in admin dashboard which will display a section of all `post_types` associated with the number of posts each of them has.

To accomplish the above I added the following code block in my `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'tp_post_counts_reference');

    function tp_post_counts_reference() {
        global $wp_meta_boxes;
        wp_add_dashboard_widget('custom_help_widget', 'Posts in all post types', 'custom_dashboard_help');
    }

    function custom_dashboard_help() {
        $types = get_post_types();
        foreach( $types as $type )
        {
            if($type != 'travelog' && $type != 'package_tour' && $type != 'hotel-info') continue;
            $typeobj = get_post_type_object( $type );

            echo '<a href="/' . $typeobj->rewrite['slug'] . '">' . $typeobj->labels->name . '</a>: ' . wp_count_posts( $type )->publish . '<br />';
        }
    }
```

But `$typeobj->rewrite['slug']` is actually outputting the post_type rather than its corresponding slug.

For example:
I have the following custom post types

**Travelog (name: Travelog, post_type: travelog, slug: travelogs)

Hotel Info (name: Hotel Info, post_type: hotel-info, slug: hotels)**

The actual output for

```
'<a href="/' . $typeobj->rewrite['slug'] . '">' . $typeobj->labels->name . '</a>: ' . wp_count_posts( $type )->publish
```

are

```
<a href="/travelog">Travelog</a>: 6
```

and

```
<a href="/hotel-info">Hotel</a>: 11
```

when I expect them to output:

```
<a href="/travelogs">Travelog</a>: 6
```

and

```
<a href="/hotels">Hotel</a>: 11
```

Please tell me what I did wrong :(

NB: My WP version is 4.7.5

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution but it is returning `home_url()` for all posts types. Seems like according to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/210545/109082, it is returning false! I added `has_archive => true;` (http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-post-types-archive-page-in-wordpress/) in my CPT. Then deactivated and reactivated the plugin. But still all post types are pointing to `home_url()`. What's went wrong?

Comment: Hi, please disregard my previous message. I had a typo in my CPT declaration. Your solution actually works! Thank you :)

Comment: I've turned it into an answer to help future visitors.  If it solved your issue, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to manually build your post type URL, I would recommend that you instead leverage the built-in WordPress function [get_post_type_archive_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_archive_link).

That would look like this:

```
function custom_dashboard_help() {
    $types = get_post_types();

    // Alternate method for testing if custom type.
    $custom_types = array( 'travelog', 'package_tour', 'hotel-info' );
    foreach( $types as $type ) {
        // If not a custom post type, don't render the link
        if( ! in_array( $type, $custom_types ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $typeobj = get_post_type_object( $type );

        // Use get_post_type_archive_link function to get URL
        echo '<a href="' . get_post_type_archive_link( $type ) . '">' . $typeobj->labels->name . '</a>: ' . wp_count_posts( $type )->publish . '<br />';
    }
}
```